# How to separate the barchart?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

How can I separate these bars, I want a distance of 1 width between each 4(referring to the 4 different types) and kindly find the image attached referring to the output that I'm getting from this code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10
Google = (10, 15, 32, 29, 13, 35, 2, 20, 27, 29)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Google, width, color='b')

Voicebase = (2, 16, 19, 30, 22, 30, 33, 4, 14, 18)

rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, Voicebase, width, color='g')

Watson = (7, 17, 14, 19, 28, 4, 4, 34, 9, 17)
rects3 = ax.bar(ind + width*2, Watson, width, color='y')  

Remeeting = (12, 21, 19, 35, 24, 6, 22, 31, 19, 14)
rects4 = ax.bar(ind + width*3, Remeeting, width, color='r')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Char edit distance')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2 )
ax.set_xticklabels(('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C1'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0], rects4[0]), ('Google', 'Voicebase','Watson', 'Remeeting'))

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to increase the spacing of your `ind` so that every 4th number is generated. This will leave space for all four of your bars.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Google = [10, 15, 32, 29, 13, 35, 2, 20, 27, 29]
Voicebase = [2, 16, 19, 30, 22, 30, 33, 4, 14, 18]
Watson = [7, 17, 14, 19, 28, 4, 4, 34, 9, 17]
Remeeting = [12, 21, 19, 35, 24, 6, 22, 31, 19, 14]

ind = np.arange(1,40,4) # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.5       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Google, width, color='b')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, Voicebase, width, color='g')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind + width*2, Watson, width, color='y')
rects4 = ax.bar(ind + width*3, Remeeting, width, color='r')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Char edit distance')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2 )
ax.set_xticklabels(('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C1'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0], rects4[0]), ('Google', 'Voicebase','Watson', 'Remeeting'))

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add another way to fix that issue(solved while experimenting) is by lowering the value of width for example it assumes the value 1 for the 4 sections plus the blank one. So by setting the value `width = 0.2` for example we'll have a nice barchart too .