# How can I adjust my plot to make it easier to read?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am generating a barplot with many elements. As shown below, the plot generated is not very easy to read. How can I adjust it to make it look better and move the columns a bit further?

[image: Plot]

Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def barchart(Gbar, Vbar, Wbar, Rbar, Dbar, Nebar, Tbar, Abar):

    N = 10
    G = Gbar

    ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups

    width = 0.12       # the width of the bars

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    rects1 = ax.bar(ind, G, width, color='b')

    V = Vbar

    rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, V, width, color='g')

    W = Wbar
    rects3 = ax.bar(ind + width*2, W, width, color='y')

    R = Rbar
    rects4 = ax.bar(ind + width*3, R, width, color='r')

    D = Dbar
    rects5 = ax.bar(ind + width * 4, D, width, color='orange')

    N = Nebar
    rects6 = ax.bar(ind + width * 5, N, width, color='black')

    T = Tbar
    rects7 = ax.bar(ind + width * 6, T, width, color='purple')

    Ab = Abar
    rects8 = ax.bar(ind + width * 7, Ab, width, color='cyan')

    # add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
    ax.set_ylabel('Char edit distance')
    ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2)
    ax.set_xticklabels(('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5', 'B1', 'B2',
                        'B3', 'B4', 'C1'))
    ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0], rects4[0], rects5[0],rects6[0],rects7[0],rects8[0]),

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)
autolabel(rects5)
autolabel(rects6)
autolabel(rects7)
autolabel(rects8)

plt.savefig('plot.png')

plt.show()
```

Note: the image attached is part of the entire image but should be more than enough to get an idea about my issue.

Comment: What is wrong with creating space between the groups of bars as in your [previous question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643176/how-to-separate-the-barchart/46643840#46643840)

Comment: That won't solve the issue of the numbers getting one over another and over the bar charts, i just need it to be much cleaner.

Comment: You might want to do horizontal bars given that you have many elements. Also make their width similar to the number you're printing. And last, use a better designed color palette. In my opinion, printing all those numbers is very dirty, particularly given the amount of lines, maybe you can increase the granularity of the ticks in your dependant variable and perhaps add some horizontal (or vertical if you do the horizontal bars) guidelines/gridlines.

Comment: Showing all the values above the bars, especially with the amount you have probably isn't going to look great as suggested above. If you were insistent on having them you could make the fontsize smaller using `fontsize=8` in `ax.text()` and make the figure itself larger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that you have a lot of bars on your graph means that having the values there may have some overlapping no matter what you do. That being said, there are a few things that can improve the look. One would be to increase the figure size. The next would be to reduce the font size of your labels. Taking the code from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643176/how-to-separate-the-barchart/46643840#46643840) and modifying it a bit:

```
Google = [10, 15, 32, 29, 13, 35, 2, 20, 27, 29]
Voicebase = [2, 16, 19, 30, 22, 30, 33, 4, 14, 18]
Watson = [7, 17, 14, 19, 28, 4, 4, 34, 9, 17]
Remeeting = [12, 21, 19, 35, 24, 6, 22, 31, 19, 14]

ind = np.arange(1,80,8)# the x locations for the groups
width = 0.9      # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,6)) #increase figure size

rects1 = ax.bar(ind, Google, width, color='b')
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, Voicebase, width, color='g')
rects3 = ax.bar(ind + width*2, Watson, width, color='y')
rects4 = ax.bar(ind + width*3, Remeeting, width, color='r')
rects5 = ax.bar(ind + width*4, Google, width, color='orange')
rects6 = ax.bar(ind + width*5, Voicebase, width, color='black')
rects7 = ax.bar(ind + width*6, Watson, width, color='purple')
rects8 = ax.bar(ind + width*7, Remeeting, width, color='cyan')

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Char edit distance')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width/2 )
ax.set_xticklabels(('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C1'))

def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom',fontsize=8) # decrease label size

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
autolabel(rects3)
autolabel(rects4)
autolabel(rects5)
autolabel(rects6)
autolabel(rects7)
autolabel(rects8)

plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.08,right=0.95)   
plt.show()
```

Gives the figure:

[image]

**Edit**

The legend documentation can be found [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html). The legend can be moved by using the `loc=` argument in `ax.legend()`. Setting a value of 1 will put the legend in the top right, 2 will be top left etc.

You can move the legend outside of your plot by using `bbox_to_anchor()`. This will reduce the size of your bar chart and therefore might lead to more overlapping in the labels. You can also try reducing the fontsize of the legend to reduce the effect of this. Using

```
ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0], rects4[0], rects5[0], rects6[0], rects7[0], rects8[0]),
          bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1),fontsize=8)
```

Gives:
[image]

Comment: That was helpful, one more issue i'm having is the overlapping legend(getting on top of some bars) can i move it away, if so how.

Answer (score 1):

Reusing part of the code in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46643176/how-to-separate-the-barchart/46643840#46643840) and implementing my suggestions the code would look like the following

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

Google = [10, 15, 32, 29, 13, 35, 2, 20, 27, 29]
Voicebase = [2, 16, 19, 30, 22, 30, 33, 4, 14, 18]
Watson = [7, 17, 14, 19, 28, 4, 4, 34, 9, 17]
Remeeting = [12, 21, 19, 35, 24, 6, 22, 31, 19, 14]


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

labels = ('A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A5','B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'C1')
y_pos = np.arange(len(labels))*4

rects1 = ax.barh(y_pos + width, Google)
rects2 = ax.barh(y_pos + 2*width, Voicebase)
rects3 = ax.barh(y_pos + 3*width, Watson)
rects4 = ax.barh(y_pos + 4*width, Remeeting)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_yticks(y_pos+2)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
ax.set_xlabel('Some label')
ax.set_ylabel('Another label')

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0], rects4[0]), ('Google', 'Voicebase','Watson', 'Remeeting'))


plt.show()
```

Which results in the following

[image]

This should provide a good starting point to keep improving the visualization of your plot. I explicitly removed the numbers as I find it too much information and makes the plot messy.

Comment: Thanks for addressing the issue but adding a numeric value in the output chart is actually a requirement.

Comment: Then you can still add it, but then it'll just still be messy. You might reduce the font size.